# Why is the first time the .net code run => it will slower then the second?

Tags: .net, clr

When i take some .net assembly and run it on machine => the JIT convert the code to native and run it. 
If i will stop the application and run it again it will load ( again ) into JIT and the JIT will convert it again and run it again.

So why is the second time of the application run will be more optimize and fester ? 
Does the JIT save somehow the first native code and then there is no need to convert the code again from the IL to native ? if its 'yes' so where the converted code ( the native ) is saved ?

Comment: You have to consider all the libraries that .net needs to load just to run you application, not just the code that you have written. So , once they are loaded in memory it is much faster.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295622/is-the-net-jit-compiled-code-cached-where

Comment: Simple disk cache might explain a lot...

Comment: How did you measure that it's actually faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably in memory. Pretty much the second time you do anything is faster as whatever you're doing is cached in various places through the system (by your disc, by the OS, ...).

When I say "it" I mean the full chain of files and libraries that are needed to make your .NET app run.

Comment: and if i clean the cache ( assume the the cache is the ram ) ? the code of the native is cleaned up .. and its still suppose to run fester in the second time

Comment: When I say cache, I mean that in a very broad sense. Your disc controller will cache the files so that it doesn't load from the platter, the OS will cache the files so it doesn't need to go to disc, etc, etc. There is no way that you can effectively clean all the caches that will kick in.

Comment: There is very little you can do on a computer that *isn't* faster a second time.