# Why Java, C# programs are faster the second time that are ran

Tags: java, c#, optimization, operating-system, jit

I know that JIT compiler compile the code on the fly and do optimization. Why when we launch the program the second time is more faster than the first? The compiler doesn't compile the program the second time we launch the program? If no where is the compiled code?

Comment: I don't close as duplicate because you asked also for Java, but for NET look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295622/where-is-the-net-jit-compiled-code-cached)

Answer (score 4):

Java still has to reserve memory, load shared libraries etc. this is done faster if it has been used recently.  This is an optimisation in the OS rather than in Java.