# Is machine-specific binary code produced by JIT saved permanently to disk as well?

Tags: c#, .net

I read the following sentence from a course note.

> JIT stands for "Just-In-Time", which means that a particular piece of
> code will be translated from CIL to binary code just before it is
> executed for the first time.

When we compile our code in C# (among others .NET languages), it will be compiled to MSIL which is permanently saved to disk.
If we then execute the MSIL for the first time, JIT translates it to machine-specific binary code.

**Question**: As the translation to the machine-specific binary code by JIT is only done once, does it mean that the machine-specific binary code is permanently saved to disk as well? If yes, where can we find the file of this machine-specific binary code?

Comment: FYI, similar question: [Where is the .NET JIT-compiled code cached?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295622/where-is-the-net-jit-compiled-code-cached)

Comment: Side note: you may want to find a place where you got "As the translation to the machine-specific binary code by JIT *is only done once*" idea from...